# Difference between two unordered deliminted lists (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, list, plsql

Is there a simple elegant method to return the difference between two unordered, delimited lists in Oracle?

Example:

- List A: a1, b4, g3, h6, t8, a0
- List B: b4, h6, a0, t8, a1

Difference: g3

Comment: Normalize it, and you can use [MINUS](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Minus)

Comment: When you say "two delimited lists", do you mean two strings?

Comment: Sorry Gabe - yes two strings so "a1, b4, g3, h6, t8, a0" and "b4, h6, a0, t8, a1"

Comment: Either string could more or less values then the other (Oracle 10g)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to `APEX_UTIL`, you can parse the strings into an array, convert them to collections, then use `MULTISET EXCEPT` (which is the same as MINUS but for collections):

```
SET SERVEROUT ON
DECLARE
  TYPE set_t IS TABLE OF varchar2(100);
  listA APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.vc_arr2;
  listB APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.vc_arr2;
  excpt set_t;
  FUNCTION to_set_t (arr IN APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.vc_arr2)
    RETURN set_t IS
    rset set_t := set_t();
  BEGIN
    rset.EXTEND(arr.COUNT);
    FOR i IN 1..arr.COUNT LOOP
      rset(i) := TRIM(arr(i));
    END LOOP;
    RETURN rset;
  END;
BEGIN
  -- parse lists into arrays
  listA := APEX_UTIL.string_to_table('a1, b4, g3, h6, t8, a0',',');
  listB := APEX_UTIL.string_to_table('b4, h6, a0, t8, a1',',');
  -- convert arrays to collections, then do the minus
  excpt := to_set_t(listA) MULTISET EXCEPT to_set_t(listB);
  -- display the results
  FOR i IN 1..excpt.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(excpt(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Result:

```
g3
```

More info on the MULTISET operators, which were introduced in 10g: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=303